# How to avoid JFrame EXIT_ON_CLOSE operation to exit the entire application?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I have a application that launches other applications, something like a dock. The problem is that if the app that I'm launching (`JFrame`) has the `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` it will also close my main application.

**I have no control what-so-ever over the applications that I'm launching.** That is, I cannot expect the application to have a good behavior and use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

What can I do to avoid this? I've tried already to use threads, but no luck. I also tried to put the main application thread in daemon, but no luck too.

I've tried putting a custom `SecurityManager` overwritting the `checkExit` method. The problem is that now even the main app can't exit. Also, it doesn`t "work" because applications that use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` as their default close operation will throw a Exception and not execute (since Swing checks the Security Manager for the exit -- System.checkExit()), failing to launch :(.

Comment: Are you launching this other application like frame.setVisible, or by creating a new process through Runtime or Process Builder?

Comment: I'm launching by reflection in a specific classloader.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to close only the frame you see, it should be `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`

EDIT:

Try intercepting the EXIT_ON_CLOSE event.

```
frame.getGlassPane() or frame.getRootPane()
```

may be useful.

Also if you have right to execute methods of the other app, you can call `setDefaultCloseOperation` again setting it to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: But I have no control on the application that I'll run. This is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit of a hack, but you can always use a `SecurityManager` to manage the other frames.

This simple example prevents a frame from exiting:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PreventExitExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PreventExitExample o = new PreventExitExample();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setSize(new Dimension(400,200));
                f.setVisible(true);

                System.setSecurityManager(new PreventExitSecurityManager());
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class PreventExitSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new SecurityException("Cannot exit this frame!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think that for example the open source project JDistro does something like that.

Comment: Hi, the problem with using a custom SecurityManager is that now even the main app can't exit. Also, it doesnt "work" because applications that use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` as their default close operation will throw a Exception and not execute (Since Swing checks the Security Manager for the exit -- System.checkExit()).

Comment: If you had run that code you might see the main app. **can** exit.

Comment: Ok, the main app can exit. But the other app won't run (i.e., the ones that have `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: @StefanDollase Removed the link, included an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can get list of all frames using
Frame's static method
public static Frame[] getFrames()

Iterate the list and check if a list member is instanceof JFrame change default close operation to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE