# how to notify user when glassfish is down

Tags: glassfish

I am using **Glassfish v3.0.1** for my project. However, Glassfish seems to be down many times. Therefore, I want to develop a mechanism that notifies me whenever Glassfish is down. Is there any option in Glassfish? If not, how can I achieve this? Further, how can I understand why Glassfish goes down? I cannot find proper explanations in logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any options in Glassfish itself and I doubt there are any (it's usually hard for a process to know when it's dead :-). Write a script that tries to connect to the service (for example, using `wget` or `curl`) or use a [system monitoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor) that watches processes.

To find out why Glassfish terminates, you must debug the problem. Here are some tipps:

- Add/enable more logging
- Search the source code for `System.exit()`. This can terminate an Java app without any trace of why it happens. ([this might help, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401281/preventing-system-exit-from-api))
- Check the standard output of the process
- Look for crash dumps; see the documentation of the Java VM which you're using.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Aaron. I will write a script to check whether the service is down. It seems the best and easier way.