# How to sandbox a class?

Tags: java, php, security, sandbox, securitymanager

Say I have a web site where people can upload their code in class form. How could I limit what can actually be done within that class?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is, write your own parser :-(

Comment: BTW - What does this have to do with PHP?  Am I right in presuming you intend to run the classes on the server?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am also interested in PHP. The question came to mind after seeing this site: http://ideone.com/

Comment: You may want to take a peek at the source of [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/), which makes it possible for people to create Java programs that fight each other in a sandbox. Their security model sounds similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html)<sup>1</sup> for the client code.  I would also recommend testing how long the code runs, and ending it if over a limit (this is more aimed at catching programmer incompetence that leads to an infinite loop, rather than deliberately malicious actions).

1. E.G. as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5401319/418556) which aims to achieve [Preventing System.exit() from API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5401281/418556).