# java create un-cooperative thread for testing

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown-hook

I've been bit a few times by a java process that wouldn't cooperate and exit cleanly (it would be buried in some low-level libraries out of my control).  I am now testing a sort of watchdog that implements a hard stop for the process at some pre-established time, `ScheduledStop`. That watchdog is a singleton class that runs an independent thread that will kill the whole process if the scheduled stop time arrives. Normally, all threads should return nicely before that hard-stop time and the program exits gracefully. If necessary however, the process kills itself, file locks are released etc.  All of this runs on Linux.

I seem to remember that even `System.exit(0)` is not fool-proof (I think if some shutdown hooks are getting stuck, the process may stay alive), so I have concocted something along the line of:

```
int pid = MyUtil.getPID();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"kill", "-9", String.valueOf(pid)});
```

Now, I'd like to test it with some *really* un-cooperative threads, and possibly some shutdown hooks that, on purpose for the test, are not doing well.

The itinial NastyThread below is not all that nasty... It ignores `InterruptionException`, but doesn't prevent `System.exit(0)`.  How can I put my VM into a state that even `exit()` doesn't terminate?

Another question is, although the watchdog thread is in theory independent, what are the conditions where other threads would completely preempt it, thus foiling the scheduled stop?

If necessary, I could launch a separate process (e.g. a simple perl script) that kills the parent (the java process) at some specified time.

```
/**
 * A Runnable that runs forever and ignores InterruptedException.
 */
private static class NastyThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Received and ignoring "+e);
                System.out.flush();
            }
            System.out.println(ScheduledStop.getInstance().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a SecurityManager to ignore or throw an Error when System.exit() is called.

BTW

```
while(true) Thread.yield();
```

or

```
for(;;);
```

will ignore interrupts as well.

Comment: mmh, I tried the `forbidSystemExitCall` described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5401402/758174  but the application still happily exits with `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: @PierreD Can you check the SecurityManager was in place?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I added a SecurityManager as suggested by @Lawrey.  Somehow the application can still happily `System.exit(0)`.

But then, I added a shutdown hook that just launches one more nasty thread!  That does the trick, and now my `ScheduledStop` class can be tested (and works).  Here is the shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(
    new NastyThread("nasty-1 (shutdown-hook)")
));
```

Here is the output of the test:

```
gp> ~$ java -cp "$CLASSPATH" com.somepackage.ScheduledStop
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT4.488S)
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT3.939S)
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT3.437S)
main would like to exit(0).
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT2.936S)
nasty-1 (shutdown-hook): Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT2.487S)
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT2.434S)
nasty-1 (shutdown-hook): Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT1.985S)
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT1.932S)
nasty-1 (shutdown-hook): Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT1.484S)
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT1.431S)
nasty-1 (shutdown-hook): Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT0.981S)
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT0.928S)
nasty-1 (shutdown-hook): Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT0.479S)
nasty-0: Stop scheduled at 20130916-111611-PDT (in PT0.426S)
Hard stop (kill -9 self=6967).
zsh: killed     java -cp "$CLASSPATH" com.somepackage.ScheduledStop
```

FWIW, here is the whole "test" code (not a real test, just taking ScheduledStop for a little drive around the block):

```
/*----------------------------------
 * all the code below is for testing
 */
/**
 * A Runnable that runs forever and ignores InterruptedException.
 */
private static class NastyThread implements Runnable {
    private final String name;

public NastyThread(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name+": received and ignoring "+e);
            System.out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println(name+": "+ScheduledStop.getInstance().toString());
    }
}
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static class ExitTrappedException extends SecurityException { }

private static void forbidSystemExitCall() {
    final SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager() {
        public void checkPermission(Permission permission ) {
            if ("exitVM".equals(permission.getName())) {
                throw new ExitTrappedException() ;
            }
        }
    };
    try {
        System.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("got: "+e);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void enableSystemExitCall() {
    System.setSecurityManager( null ) ;
}

/**
 * Spawn an un-cooperative thread, then kill itself after a few seconds.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final File lockFile = new File("testStop.lock");
    final Period runFor = Period.seconds(5);
    try (HplFileLock lock = FileUtil.getFileLockOrExit(lockFile, 0)) {
        ScheduledStop.getInstance().runFor(runFor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
        System.err.flush();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    // disallow System.exit()
    forbidSystemExitCall();

    // launch a pesky thread that ignores interruption
    Runnable r = new NastyThread("nasty-0");
    new Thread(r).start();

    // further, install a shutdown hook that just launches one more NastyThread!
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new NastyThread("nasty-1 (shutdown-hook)")));

    // now wait 2 seconds and try to exit
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("main would like to exit(0).");
    System.out.flush();
    System.exit(0);
}
```