# How to include script and run it into kubernetes yaml?

Tags: openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin

It is how to run simple batch in kubernetes yaml (helloworld.yaml):

```
...
image: "ubuntu:14.04"
command: ["/bin/echo", "hello", "world"]
...
```

In Kubernetes i can deploy that like this:

```
$ kubectl create -f helloworld.yaml
```

Suppose i have a batch script like this (script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please wait....";
sleep 5
```

Is there way to include the script.sh into `kubectl create -f` so it can run the script. Suppose now helloworld.yaml edited like this:

```
...
image: "ubuntu:14.04"
command: ["/bin/bash", "./script.sh"]
...
```

Answer (score 47):

I'm using this approach in OpenShift, so it should be applicable in Kubernetes as well.

Try to put your script into a configmap key/value, mount this configmap as a volume and run the script from the volume.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hello-world-job
spec:
  parallelism: 1    
  completions: 1    
  template:         
    metadata:
      name: hello-world-job
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: hello-world-scripts-volume
        configMap:
          name: hello-world-scripts
      containers:
      - name: hello-world-job
        image: alpine
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /hello-world-scripts
            name: hello-world-scripts-volume
        env:
          - name: HOME
            value: /tmp
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          echo "scripts in /hello-world-scripts"
          ls -lh /hello-world-scripts
          echo "copy scripts to /tmp"
          cp /hello-world-scripts/*.sh /tmp
          echo "apply 'chmod +x' to /tmp/*.sh"
          chmod +x /tmp/*.sh
          echo "execute script-one.sh now"
          /tmp/script-one.sh
      restartPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  data:
    script-one.sh: |
      echo "script-one.sh"
      date
      sleep 1
      echo "run /tmp/script-2.sh now"
      /tmp/script-2.sh
    script-2.sh: |
      echo "script-2.sh"
      sleep 1
      date
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    name:  hello-world-scripts
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

Comment: I just want to stress the importance of `restartPolicy: Never`, because otherwise you might get `CrashLoopBackOff`s. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794554/308451).

Comment: Hey @JBSnorro thanks for the comment. My doubt is what happens if we set the `restartPolicy: Never` and our script fails due to some error?

Comment: can we bash over shell in pod

Comment: Is there a need to use the list object? I was able to use multiple scripts and execute them as specified in the answer using a deployment without using list. But i am not able to figure out why list was used in the answer. Can anyone help please

Comment: Why do we get the `CrashLoopBackOff` if we do not define the `restartPolicy`?

Answer (score 15):

As explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71356#issuecomment-441169334), you could use the `defaultMode: 0777` property as well, an example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-script
data:
  test.sh: |
    echo "test1"
    ls
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: test-script
        configMap:
          name: test-script
          defaultMode: 0777
      containers:
      - command:
        - sleep
        - infinity
        image: ubuntu
        name: locust
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /test-script
            name: test-script
```

You can enter into the container shell and execute the script `/test-script/test.sh`

Comment: Nice example; `defaultMode` or `fsGroup` is required to have the required permissions to run the script

Comment: You save my day!!!

Comment: when i add default mode as 0755, still my configmap has the 777 permission.
`lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          22 Aug 16 19:31 parameters.conf -> ..data/parameters.conf`