# Kubernetes env variable containing another cat'd variable

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to get either my deployment manifest or a configmap approach to pass in such a set of variables:

```
DIRECTORY=/home/test  
TOKEN=$(cat $(DIRECTORY)/token)
```

In both my deployment manifest, and my configmap attempts, the `TOKEN=$(cat $(DIRECTORY)/token):` gets set literally, and not resolved within the pod (basically it should be: `TOKEN=/home/test/token`)

Is it not possible to set vars this way with Kubenernetes? Is this due to the fact that the pod expects { } around the variables and not (  ) like kubenetes requires?

Comment: The expression `$(some command)` is a shell expression. Kubernetes is not your shell. You can do something like that at runtime in the `ENTRYPOINT` of your image, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If I good understood, you want to pass some environment variables to pod and then use them with another environment variable?

It can be achieved in `Deployment` using [Dependent Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/).

> When you create a Pod, you can set dependent environment variables for the containers that run in the Pod. To set dependent environment variables, you can use $(VAR_NAME) in the value of env in the configuration file.

**Test YAML**

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dependent-envars-demo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: dependent-envars-demo
      args:
        - while true; do echo -en '\n'; printf DIRECTORY=$DIRECTORY'\n'; printf TOKEN=$TOKEN'\n'; sleep 300; done;
      command:
        - sh
        - -c
      image: busybox
      env:
        - name: SERVICE_PORT
          value: "80"
        - name: DIRECTORY
          value: "/home/test"
        - name: TOKEN
          value: "$(DIRECTORY)/token"
```

To verify if this is working, you should check logs.

```
DIRECTORY=/home/test
TOKEN=/home/test/token
```

Regarding [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/), it should be consider as normal text, not bash commands. It help separate your code from configuration and it's mostly `key: value` type. However, there are some specific scenario, where `ConfigMap` contains script body and later it can be used in pod. Example can be found in [another Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50506354/11148139) or [USING KUBERNETES CONFIGMAPS AS CODE](https://starkandwayne.com/blog/silly-kubectl-trick-8-redux-configmaps/) article.

Last thing I want to mention that `Kubernetes` have `ConfigMap` for configuration changes and [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) for more sensitive data.

Comment: In your Test YAML code, would I be able to set a value such as ```value: "$(cat $(DIRECTORY)/token)"``` ?

Comment: If you want to run bash commands inside pod you would need to follow [Run a command in a shell](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell)  This way you could use bash inside the pod. But alternative solution could be to use [Init Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to prepare some configuration before deploying another container.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same feature.. however, there is no straightforward way as per my research.

Alternatively, this pattern can work & you can generalize it:

```yaml
  image:...
  command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  args:
    - >-
      export TOKEN=$(cat /path/to/token)
      exec /bin/original/entrypoint
```

Comment: `exec /bin/original/entrypoint` Otherwise your code breaks signals propagation.

Comment: Yeah! I agree.. exec forces the program to take PID (process ID) 1 in its Linux namespace.