Kubernetes ConfigMap expets 'string' in valid YAML
I'm trying to set up a Cron Job in Kubernetes using a ConfigMap, and mount a shell script to a volume. I have valid YAML, but line 9 throws an error that it's expecting a string:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: elasticdump-configmap
  namespace: default
data:
  job.schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  spec:
    restartPolicy: OnFailure
    containers:
    - name: elasticdump
      image: elasticdump/elasticsearch-dump
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "elasticdump.sh"]
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/data
        name: blob01
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 1Gi
      limits:
        memory: 5Gi
  volumes:
     - name: blob01
       persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-blob
       configMap:
        name: elasticdump-configmap
        items:
          - key: elasticdump.sh
            path: elasticdump.sh

I know I'm doing something wrong in the structure of the YAML, but I'm very new to Kubernetes, so would appreciate even a hint of what to do.

As it states in docs:

A ConfigMap is an API object that lets you store configuration for
other objects to use.

So, it's not possible to define a CronJob such way. Please, look at special k8s Object called CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: elasticdump-configmap
  namespace: default
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: elasticdump
            image: elasticdump/elasticsearch-dump
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "elasticdump.sh"]
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/data
              name: blob01
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: 1Gi
              limits:
                memory: 5Gi
          volumes:
          - name: blob01
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: pvc-blob
          - name: elasticdump-configmap
            configMap:
              name: elasticdump-configmap
              items:
              - key: elasticdump.sh
                path: elasticdump.sh
          restartPolicy: OnFailure


Sorry, actually it doesn't work. The Cron Job you specified fails, because the elasticdump pod spun up by the job can't find the elasticdump.sh script. I need this to be a ConfigMap object, that contains the script, but has a schedule.

where do you define lasticdump.sh? CnfigMap is used to store some data in sort of key-value storage. If you need to execute custom shell script you can insert it entity directly into command.
Here you can find an example how to include whole script into command - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674108/how-to-include-script-and-run-it-into-kubernetes-yaml
