# Is this a safe way to synchronize a block of code?

Tags: java, synchronization

In our application, there's a section of code that runs continuously reading and adjusting files. Just to give you a sense of what's going on:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) { //Yeah, I know...
            Path currentFileName = getNextFile();
            String string = readFile(currentFileName);
            Files.deleteFile(currentFileName);
            string = string.replaceAll("Hello", "Blarg");
            writeFile(currentFileName);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("It's all ogre now.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in our code is a method that might-but-usually-doesn't run on the same thread as the above code, that we use to exit the application.

```
private void shutdown() {
    if(fileReader != null)
        fileReader = null;

    System.exit(0); //Don't blame me, I didn't write this code
}
```

As might be obvious, there's a potential Race Condition in this code, whereby if `shutdown()` is called between retrieving the file and then writing it back out, it'll potentially cause the file to be completely lost. This is, obviously, undesirable behavior.

There's a thousand issues with this code (outside the scope of just what I've shown here), but the main issue I need to resolve is the bad behavior where processing a file can be cut off halfway through with no recourse. My proposed solution involves simply wrapping the while loop in a `synchronized` block and putting a block around the `System.exit` call in `shutdown`.

So my changed code would look like this:

```
private Object monitor = new Object();
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            synchronized(monitor) {
                Path currentFileName = getNextFile();
                String string = readFile(currentFileName);
                Files.deleteFile(currentFileName);
                string = string.replaceAll("Hello", "Blarg");
                writeFile(currentFileName);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("It's all ogre now.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

private void shutdown() {
    synchronized(monitor) {
        if(fileReader != null)
            fileReader = null;

         System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The main thing I'm worried about is the `System.exit(0);` call, where I'm not certain about the total behavior behind the scenes of the call. Is there a risk that a side-effect of `System.exit` will be to release the lock on `monitor`, and thus risk the contents of the loop in `run` being executed partially before `System.exit` has caused the JVM to halt? Or will this code guarantee that the execution will never attempt a shutdown part-way through the handling of an individual file?

Note: before some armchair programmers step in with alternatives, I'd like to point out that what I've put here is a truncated version of about 4000 lines of code all stashed in a single class. Yes, it is awful. Yes, it makes me regret my chosen profession. I am not here looking for alternate solutions to this problem, I am only trying to determine if this specific solution will work, or if there's some critical flaw that would preclude it from ever working as I expect.

Comment: How about setting a boolean in `shutdown` and checking it in `run` to see whether the JVM is about to exit?

Comment: Do multiple threads do the read/write thing?

Comment: (Aside: setting a variable to null before `System.exit` is probably unnecessary).

Comment: @GhostCat I haven't accepted an answer because none of the answers have tried to prove their claims, like by citing documentation or implementation details. I'm not comfortable accepting an answer for an issue like this, where simply running the code cannot prove the legitimacy of the solution, if the answer only claims "this will work!" without substantiating that claim.

Answer (score 2):

> Or will this code guarantee that the execution will never attempt a shutdown part-way through the handling of an individual file?

This code guarantees that a shutdown *initiated here* will not occur part-way through handling of an individual file. Perhaps obviously, somewhere else in your code could invoke `System.exit`, and you have no protection from that.

You might want to consider [preventing `System.exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401281/preventing-system-exit-from-api) from being invoked, and then cause your code to shut down gracefully (i.e. by normal completion of the `main` method).

Comment: If simply eliminating `System.exit` were a real option, I'd gladly take it. Unfortunately, I'm not able to make that decision unless I'm given permission to completely overhaul the code—and as of right now, that's very unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

In case you really have multiple threads calling the different methods, using `synchronized` like this is actually a clever idea, as it takes care of that "multiple threads" thing.

You could consider reducing the scope of the first block:

```
Path currentFileName = getNextFile();
String string = readFile(currentFileName);
synchronized(monitor) {
```

*reading* the file alone shouldn't be a problem. (of course, unless your code here has to guarantee that a Path returned by `getNextFile()` gets fully processed).

Answer (score 2):

If the code is executing in the `synchronized` block and the blocks synchronize on the same object, **and** the methods invoked in the `synchronized` block in the `while` loop operate entirely on the same thread as their caller, then there is no risk of the file-related processes being interrupted by *that* invocation of `System.exit`.

This said, it does look like a debatable patch only slightly improving debatable code.

There may also be a more concrete risk of starvation, as the while loop as displayed just seems to spam those file operations as fast as possible, hence the attempt to acquire the lock when exiting may not succeed.

A general direction to explore would be to transform the infinite `while` loop into a `ScheduledExecutorService` + `Runnable`, executing every x amount of time with its own monitor to prevent overlapping operations on the same file(s), and gracefully terminating it when the `shutdown` method is invoked.

Comment: *"it does look like a debatable patch only slightly improving debatable code."* You are not the slightest bit wrong. If we had funding to completely overhaul and redo the whole program, I'd be doing that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **shutdown hook**. From the javadocs:

> A shutdown hook is simply an initialized but unstarted thread. When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)

From this, you could provide a shutdown hook from your file class as follows:

```
public Thread getShutdownHook() {
    return new Thread(() -> {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            // gracefully handle the file object
        }
    });
}
```

This will be called when `Runtime.getRuntime().exit()` is called (which is called by `System.exit()`). Since it is also synchronized on the monitor object, if the file is in use by the other thread, the shutdown hook will block until it is free.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful to my issue because the "graceful handing of the file object" is not the defect I'm trying to fix. What I'm trying to fix is the spurious execution of `run` which may-or-may-not be halfway through an iteration of its inner loop when `System.shutdown(0)` is called.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you cope with concurrent `System.exit()`, other reasons remain which can lead to sudden break of execution, like power outage or hardware error.

So you better do not remove the file before the new version is written. Do something like:

```
Path currentFileName = getNextFile();
Path tmpFileName = currentFileName+suffix();
String string = readFile(currentFileName);
string = string.replaceAll("Hello", "Blarg");
writeFile(tmpFileName);
Files.move(tmpFileName, currentFileName);
```

Comment: As I emphasized in the question, this code is just a pared down version of what's actually happening. What's **actually** happening involves 1) reading from a Message Queue, 2) Reading from (and later writing to) a database, 3) Making a Webservice call, 4) Performing File I/O across several networked devices. While you are correct that this code can fail for other reasons like power failure, addressing that issue is in no way shape or form a valid solution to what I am trying to solve.