# How to get the window closed event after I invoke the main method of DatabaseManagerSwing class in HSQLDB jar?

Tags: java, swing, hsqldb

I am using HSQL in memory database in my java application. I am opening the `GUI manager` provided by the HSQLDB by invoking main method of `DatabaseManagerSwing` class. It opened successfully.

I need to *register a callback* or *notified when the user closes the window manually*. I am not able to find anything similar in the docs and after seeing the code of `DatabaseManagerSwing` class, I think it is not supported.

The `stop` method simply clear its variables and does not call any other method. As I was thinking if it supports this, it must store the callback objects somewhere and finally call them in stop method. But unfortunately, nothing.

Is there any way or a workaround to get this done ? I need to perform some action when user closes the window.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5401319/418556) (which implements a `SecurityManager`).

Comment: Actually the swing code is libraries'. I can't control it. Maybe, it is not a swing problem but a question related to library itself. As to, is there something in the hsqldb  API that can make it possible. I think I am right, but in case it is somehow possible, please elaborate a little as I not able to grasp it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a shutdownhook so that, it runs when the program terminates. But that's not it. Make sure while starting the HSQL Database Manager, do not pass the *--noexit* argument. By not passing the argument, JVM will exit when you close the Database Manager window.

By adding this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
        // do your stuff
    }) {
    });
```

You can do what you want to do when the window is manually closed by the user.